# Will ESPER CEP work on Hadoop or Spark platform

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper, bigdata

I have used ESPER CEP in standalone system. Is ESPER cloud compatible? Will it run on Hadoop or Spark Platforms
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Esper runs in any JVM environment with any programming language. Esper have a .NET version too that runs on any CLR. So Esper can run as part of a Spark and-or Hadoop stack. If you use Esper in a stateless way, and only do filtering, transformation etc.., you don't worry about where the state lives when it fails and the world is easy. If you want to use Esper in a stateful way, you must worry where the state lives, and that requires more thinking. With stateful I mean using aggregations, data windows, patterns etc etc. So when you have the stateful use, such as a count for example, and maybe you need to make sure the count is not lost when the job moves or the system reboots, that is when you may need EsperHA.